# ID for each item JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, function, onclick

```
   <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" style="font-size: 50px;color: red" id="'.$item['id'].'" onclick="changeH()"></a>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function changeH() {
           if (document.getElementById('<?php echo $item['id'];?>').className == "glyphicon glyphicon-heart")
               document.getElementById('<?php echo $item['id'];?>').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty";
           else {
               document.getElementById('<?php echo $item['id'];?>').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-heart";
           }
       }
   </script>
```

I want to display an empty heart in each item AND when I cliked on one, it will display a full heart. It works for me only when I make a character or integer id but no with PHP.

Help me Please !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're approaching this completely wrong. You're creating a new `<script>` tag for each link, and you keep overwriting the `changeH()` function with a new function that's specific to the latest link you generated.

Instead try something like this:

```
<?php foreach($links as $item): ?>
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" style="font-size: 50px;color: red" id="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" onclick="changeH(this);"></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<script>
    function changeH(link) {
        if (link.className == "glyphicon glyphicon-heart") {
            link.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty";
        }
        else {
            link.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-heart";
        }
    }
</script>
```

I'd suggest reading up on JavaScript event handling on MDN.
(You can also implement the CSS class changing better, but that's not the scope of this question right now)

Comment: i have already foreach to display other columns from the table item :/

Comment: That's fine, the foreach is not really the point. The point is to just have one `<script>` tag where you define the `changeH` function, and call that function from the event handler of all `<a>` tags, passing `this` as the parameter. You don't even need id's this way (at least not for changing the icon).